# LinkedIn API Changes

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Our LinkedIn API calls started failing. Even the simplest `/v1/prople/~` calls started erroring with `This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs`.

So we're trying to migrate stuff using the new `/v2` way, but somehow it seems not to be working. For example (and after requesting a token with the new scopes), a simple request to `/v2/me` fails to return the fields we need (amongst others, `headline` and `location`). When asking explicitly for these fields, we're told that we don't have access to them - even tho the token was generated using the `r_basicprofile r_liteprofile r_emailaddress` scopes.

We've tried numerous combinations and variations of asking for certain fields, projections, formats, etc from the Microsoft docs - with no avail and we're wondering whether the `/v2` API is actually something functional - is there anyone successful using it, and if so, how?

A sample CURL request with an obfuscated `Bearer` would be a good way for us to understand what we're doing wrong - but it seems that even the simplest requests verbatim from the docs just fail.

EDIT: After some research, it looks like Microsoft changed their versioned API behavior without being consistent in the docs. Some docs point to `r_liteprofile` and some others to `r_basicprofile` as the default way to go now without being "Linkedin Partners". We were previously requesting `r_emailaddress` too and the `headline` and `location` parts of the `r_basicprofile` bits were used in our code in many different places.

Comment: Please keep your questions (and answers) objective. This isn't the place for subjective rants or complaints. Meanwhile, the changes were announced a half-year ago, along with both a migrate-by date and a migration guide going into more detail.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Done.

Answer (score -2):

These were two problems:

- Some of the fields are removed from v1 (headline, email, location etc),
- Most of the fields requested are not available in v2 without special scopes, but these scopes are very poorly documented as being part of a "LinkedIn Partner" program our app has to be accepted in before we can now use them.

The basic answer to this question is that LinkedIn (Microsoft) made backward-incompatible changes to their API.